# How to extend entity class?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework and Mysql. And I have Entity classes for each tables.

But I do not know how to extend fields into entity class **that does not defined in DB**.

For example)  I have test table and the table have id, price and qty fields.

My entity class is like this,

```
[Table('test')]
public class Test
{
  [Key]
  public int id {get; set;}
  public decimal price {get; set;}
  public int qty {get; set;}
}
```

Now, I need subtotal field in Test class. (for some reason, **I can not modify DB**)

so I try to make the Test class as Partial class,

```
[Table('test')]
public partial class Test
{
  [Key]
  public int id {get; set;}
  public decimal price {get; set;}
  public int qty {get; set;}
}

public partial class Test 
{
  public decimal? subTotal {get; set;}
}
```

Then I got an error : It say, 'Unknown column 'Extent1.subTotal' in 'field list''

Anybody know, How can I add the subTotal field into Test class without changing DB structure?

Please advice me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `NotMappedAttribute` for any properties you want to have in your model, but do not want Entity Framework to map to your database.

```
 [Table('test')]
    public class Test
    {
      [Key]
      public int id {get; set;}
      public decimal price {get; set;}
      public int qty {get; set;}
      [NotMapped]
      public decimal? subTotal {get; set;}
    }
```